# Best way to find if a subgraph has a cycle

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I am implementing Kruskal's algorithm to find a minimal spanning tree of a connected graph $G$. If $H$ is a subtree of $G$, does anyone know a smart way of checking if $H+e$, where $e$ is an edge of $G$ not in $H$, has a cycle, i.e. is not anymore a tree?

EDIT: $H$ is not necessarily connected.

Comment: The point is that with Kruskal's algorithm the subgraph obtained at each step is not necessary a connected subtree.

Comment: Hmm. So $e$ either connects two subcomponents of $H$ or is a cycle edge?

Comment: No, $e$ can also simply extend $H$ without making $H$ into a tree if $H$ was a forest or without adding a cycle.

Comment: Take $G$ as a complete graph of order $n\geq 3$ and the vertex set of $H$ as two random vertices of $G$.

Comment: Try using the [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (also called "union and find").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the edge:

$e = (a, b)$

and the subtree:

$H= {T_0, T_1, ..., T_n}$

so let $a_T$ be the component of $H$ containing $a$ and define $b_T$ similarly. We have:

1. $a_T = b_T\Longrightarrow e$ is a cycle edge of the shared component.
2. $a_T \neq b_T\Longrightarrow e$ connects those components.
3. One of $a$ of $b$ is not in H $\Longrightarrow e$ extends the component ($T$).
4. Neither $a$ nor $b$ are in $H$ $\Longrightarrow e$ is a new $T$ in $H$.

Some of that notation might be a bit unclear, but I think that covers it.